# Decorrelation of SQL subquery with inequality predicate

Tags: sql, apache-spark, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to decorrelate query which looks like that:

```
select A.id, A.other_id A.data, A.data2, 
(select count(*) from B where B.id = A.id and B.data < A.data),
(select count(*) from B where B.id = A.id and B.data < A.data and A.other_id = B.other_id),
(select count(*) from B where B.id = A.id and B.data < A.data and B.sth is True)
from A
```

I tried to something like `select ... from A left join B on B.data < A.data where ...` But the result is not exactly the same and it's much slower.

Is there any reasonable way to decorrelate such a query?

I want to run this in spark which doesn't support correlated subqueries with inequality predicate.

Or maybe there is a different way to achieve the same result that would work with spark.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this with conditional aggregation:

```
select A.id, A.other_id A.data, A.data2, 
       sum(case when b.data < a.data then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when b.other_id = a.other_idid and b.data < a.data then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when b.data < a.data and b.sth is true then 1 else 0 end)
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
group by A.id, A.other_id A.data, A.data2
```

Comment: Works correctly, unfortunately within spark runs very slow (~20x slower then correlated query on postgresql)

Comment: @Purple. . . That it is slower doesn't surprise me.  Your question was how to rewrite the code.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't phrase it correctly. Anyway thanks a lot for help.